# How can i output the children of a process as a number in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, process

I want to output to a text.log the count of the childrens of a process searching them by name not with PID. For example i want to count the processes of firefox by name and output them in the text file as a number "6" .

Comment: Do you mean `pgrep firefox | wc -l > filename`?

Comment: One last thing. How can i change line in the text so it doesnt overwrite it but count it from 12 to 0 for example?

Comment: @Cyrus What if two firefox processes have been started?

Comment: @hek2mgl: He gets all PIDs of all firefox processes.

Comment: @ihavename: Do you mean `grep firefox | wc -l >> filename` to append the output to filename?

Comment: @Cyrus Yes thank you again mate, i am new to bash terminal so i have some newbie questions.  Thank you!

Comment: @Cyrus I wanted to say that you only find procs which are named firefox. But you don't care about father/child relations. `ps --ppid` will do that.

Comment: @hek2mgl: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

By PID using the ps command:

```
ps --ppid PID_OF_PROC | wc -l
```

If you need it recursively, meaning childs of childs included then use:

```
ps x --ppid PID_OF_PROC | wc -l
```